# indent of subsections changes after using belowcaptionskip IEEEtran

Tags: latex, indentation

I am using the following code to reduce spacing before and after figures and equations in order to save space

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{\normalsize
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.1cm}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.1cm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-0.2cm}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-0.2cm}}
```

however, this changes the indent of the (sub)subsections of the other. For example, in this code

```
\subsubsection{Test} I try to reduce indent here.
```

The 'Test' appears more right than without using the aforementioned commands. I tried using`\setlength\parindent{0.3cm}`, but this changes the indent for all text and not the headings of sections that I would like to change.

Comment: What happens if you don't include the changes as part of an update to `\normalsize`, but instead, just add `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{.}{..}\setlength{.}{..} ... \setlength{.}{..}}`?

Comment: Dear Werner, it seems to work with your proposal. thank you so much!